# Inner Join with the same table return out-of-memory

Tags: database, sqlite, inner-join

I have a table like

```
+----+----------+----------+---------+
| ID | ParentID | IsSource |  Value  |
+----+----------+----------+---------+
|  1 |        1 |        1 | Car     |
|  2 |        1 |        0 | Coche   |
|  3 |        2 |        1 | Car     |
|  4 |        2 |        0 | Auto    |
|  5 |        3 |        1 | House   |
|  6 |        3 |        0 | Hogar   |
|  7 |        4 |        1 | Bus     |
|  8 |        4 |        0 | Autobus |
+----+----------+----------+---------+
```

But with 1.6 million entries

I like to get the entries that contains same Value but different ID (or ParentID) and only for the entries with "IsSource=1"
To do that I'm using a INNER JOIN statement with the same table

```
SELECT seg1.ParentID , seg2.ParentID FROM tblSegment seg1
INNER JOIN tblSegment seg2 ON
seg1.Value  = seg2.Value  AND
seg1.ID!= seg2.ID
WHERE seg1.isSource = 1 and seg2.isSource = 1
```

Although I have indexed for all the fields I get an out-of-memory error
I have used many variants of the query above with the same result

Are there any other way of getting the expected result in a reasonable time?

Comment: You say `IsSource=1` but the query says `IsSource=0` so you may want to decide which you mean :) What is the distribution (ie how many rows are interesting, ie have the correct value of IsSource, of the ones in the table?) Also, your table has different column names than the sample query.

Comment: Sorry Joachim, you are right. A "Copy&Paste" issue
I have already fixed that

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be too much data for your SQLite database.

You could try [creating a VIEW](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_views.htm) maybe that works. Otherwise you maybe should change your database model so that you don't need that join.

Answer (score 0):

A `GROUP BY` may be easier for the database to handle, although a little strange to select ParentID where ID differs your sample query would go something like this;

```
SELECT MIN(ParentID) p1, MAX(ParentID) p2
FROM tblSegment
WHERE IsSource=1
GROUP BY Value
HAVING COUNT(ID)>1
```

If you want to find where ParentID differs, instead use;

```
SELECT MIN(ParentID) p1, MAX(ParentID) p2
FROM tblSegment
WHERE IsSource=1
GROUP BY Value
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ParentID)>1
```